# JMETER: how to exclude proxy

Tags: web-services, wsdl, wso2, jmeter

I've a web service built on WSO02 that run in a virtual machine running on my laptop.

My laptop IP: 10.118.xx.yyy

My web service wsdl: http://192.168.zz.kkk/wso001/services/OperCupPrepareProxy?wsdl (NOTE: 192.168.29.128 is the IP of my WSO2 ESB on my virtual machine)

I can invoke my web service using SOAP UI running directly on my laptop (i.e NOT running in the virtual machine ...), with NO proxy setting and all it's working right

Now I'd like to test my web service using JMeter running directly on my laptop (i.e NOT running in the virtual machine ...), and invoking the web service that run inside the virtual machine with WSO2.

JMETER respond ....

Response code: 500
Response message: Internal Server Error

```
<faultstring>The endpoint reference (EPR) for the Operation not found is /wso001/services/OperCupPrepareService?wsdl and the WSA Action = null. If this EPR was previously reachable, please contact the server administrator.</faultstring>
```

How can I set my JMETER to invoke my web service?

Thank in advance

Cesare

Comment: I forgot .... I'm using JMETER 2.11 r1554548

Comment: Is this web service accessible if you launch it from browser of you laptop (not virtual machine)??